# Refused to display 'https://abcd.ac.in/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin

Tags: html, angular, iframe, angular8

I'm trying to invoke a website inside an iframe but I get an error in console Refused to display 'https://abcd.ac.in/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin.
[image]
i've tried an alternatives  and  still it throws the same error

Comment: Did you try change the settings of your server?

Comment: @FabioAssuncao I want to add google meet homepage in my iframe

Answer (score 0):

It means that the site you're trying to put into iframe has it blocked. There is a discussion already on how to do it anyway. You may want to have a look at this topic:

[Overcoming "Display forbidden by X-Frame-Options"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666423/overcoming-display-forbidden-by-x-frame-options#answer-7469997)